# Proof of "Fundamental Theorem of Algebra' using Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am studying Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

> $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed

It is enough to prove theorem by showing this statement $1$,

> Statement $1$. If $E/\mathbb C$ is finite extension, then $\mathbb C=E$.

And to prove Statement $1$, it is enough to show Statement $2$

> Statement $2$.  Suppose $E/\mathbb R$ is finite extension, and $K$ be normal closure of $E/\mathbb R$.
>   Then, $K=\mathbb C$.

Now my goal is to show Statement $2$.

Since all fields on above are characteristic $0$, all extensions are separable.

Therefore $K/\mathbb R$ is Galois Extension. And the book states $K/\mathbb R$ is obviously finite extension.

However I couldn't catch why $[K:\mathbb R]<\infty$.

Comment: Normal closures of finite extensions are finite - it is the compositum of the finitely many conjugates of K, all of which are finite extensions, and so the whole thing is finite.

Comment: Statement 2 is wrong for $E=\mathbb R$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg right, I made no sense. My bad!

Comment: Thanks for your kindness